# Convert datetime to local python

Tags: python, datetime

I have been reading quite some time answers and couldn't really drive into results.

I have the following code:

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>a = '2013-08-23T23:37:38+0000'
>>>dt = datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
>>>print   dt.date()
2013-08-23
>>>print   dt.time()
23:37:38
```

What is the simplest way to output this result (assuming of course that `a` is unknown) given that we live in Central Europe. So it should be "daylight saving-proof" as well.

In winter:

```
2013-08-24
00:37:38
```

In summer:

```
2013-08-24
01:37:38
```

If it only needs default libraries it would be great.

---

**Some more info**

I dived into the libraries after my question. My above 3rd line should be better be:
`dt = datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')`. However a bug came out in 2.7.5 python (OS X if it matters) and had some trouble finding the `%z`. If you have trouble change version, if not ignore this. Of course the `strptime()` is just simpler level of `dateutil.parser` mentioned in the two answers so it can better be used instead of my code above.

Comment: Could you explain in a sentence or two what exactly you'd like to achieve. Your example doesn't make it clear (to me anyway).

Comment: If a is unknown do you want to retrieve the current time or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the useful dateutil package and the pytz one for exemple convert to paris timezone

```
from dateutil import parser
import pytz
FR = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris') # there is the summer offset changing in this zone
date = parser.parse("2013-08-23T23:37:38+0000")
datefr = date.astimezone(FR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
from dateutil import parser
import pytz


date = parser.parse('2013-08-23T23:37:38+0000')

CET = pytz.timezone('CET')
date = date.astimezone(CET)

print date.date()  # prints 2013-08-24
print date.time()  # prints 01:37:38
```